# vegas background jquery plugin redirect to url after last slide

Tags: jquery

I am using the vegas background jQuery plugin located here  http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/  and the slideshow loops. My question is twofold:

1. How do I stop the slideshow from looping (which file, and what code to I edit or insert)?
2. I would like at the end of the last slide for the slideshow to redirect to a URL (which file, and what code to I edit or insert)?

Comment: What Happens In Vegas Stays In Vegas... unless you share your code.

Comment: The code is too long to insert but it is the same code that is downloaded from Vegas site http://jaysalvat.github.io/vegas/releases/latest/vegas.zip

Comment: You made ABSOLUTELY NO CHANGES TO THEIR CODE?  Or what?  If you did *anything* yourself, then *it* is included in *their* code? I personally live in Vegas, but you're going to have to do more work to convince me to suspend disbelief.

Comment: Now that's going to be difficult but all I can say that I only changed the slides in the index file, it runs exactly like the demo which loops as shown at http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlideshowAudio/

Comment: I'm not sure that you're getting the point.  The demo works, right? Your code doesn't, right?  And you want us all to guess the difference between them?  How about you make it easy and point out in this question exactly what you did (via code) and what is not going as you planned?  Mystery novels are fun, but only when the answer can be had.

Comment: The demo (which is my code) does not work as it relates to not looping which is the first part of my question.  As you can see at the demo after the last slide it loops to the first which is what I seek to eliminate, as well I'd like after that last slide for the slide to redirect to a specified link.  I've not altered the code from what is used to deliver tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlideshowAudio

Answer (score 0):

```
$.vegas('slideshow', {
  backgrounds:pictures, 
  delay: 4000,
  walk:function(step) {
    if (step == 3){
      //this will stop
      $.vegas('stop');
      //this will redirect
      document.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'.
    }
  }
})('overlay');
```

Comment: I tried this in the unedited script downloaded from Vegas (code to long to post) http://jaysalvat.github.io/vegas/releases/latest/vegas.zip    and I'm not certain exactly what it needs to replace or where it is placed.  Thanks for your assistance Wayne and others.

Comment: That code only contains the plugin itself. Where is the code that uses the plugin? My code above is an example of code that uses the plugin.

Comment: @WayneEllery Seems like the OP is having fun withholding anything they have actually done and watching us try to guess.

Comment: $.vegas( 'slideshow', { 
        backgrounds: pictures,
        delay: 4000
     })( 'overlay' );

Comment: I've modified my code above to be in sync with your code. As I don't have the full code I haven't been able to test this.

Comment: Hey Wayne, Do you have any suggestions on how to embed a preload autoplay video inside my last slide wit a different length than other slides ?

Comment: Take a look at video.js: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/setup.md. What do you mean by a different length?

Comment: I'm sorry, by length I mean I would like the last slide in the slideshow to contain the video which would require the length of that final slide to be longer than the length of all the other slides.  Is this possible as well inserting a video inside of a slide with video.js?  Thanks!

Comment: Wayne your instructions on stopping and redirecting work perfectly.  Is there a way to time the redirect (let's say for 4 seconds which is the time the slides transition at) as presently there is an abrupt redirect that throws off the flow of the presentation.   Thank you.

Comment: The script works perfect with 1 exception. If the user clicks on a slide which pauses the slideshow, or goes to a previous slide, the slideshow doesn't stop at slide 45 and redirect, it loops.  Therefore I need the stop to be specific to a slide and not a step process. 

    $.vegas( 'slideshow', { 
        backgrounds: pictures,
        delay: 4000,
 walk:function(step) {
  if (step == 45){
      //this will stop 
   $.vegas('stop');
  //this will redirect
 window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = '/rop/history/index.html';
 }, 4000);
   }}})( 'overlay' );

Comment: Are you saying that if they jump to slide 45 by clicking on it, then it doesn't stop?

Comment: @Wayne Ellery your solution worked great for years but some code had to be added to my site to have slideshow not autoplay that has knocked your solution out of wack - May I share the code?

Comment: @WayneEllery your solution worked great for years but some code had to be added to my site to have slideshow not autoplay that has knocked your solution out of wack - May I share the code?

Comment: @user3741546 sure. It was a long time ago. Can u post a jsfiddle?

Comment: @WayneEllery  I have not a clue what a jsfiddle is - May I email the file(s) to you?

Comment: @WayneEllery here's the link -  Please note that this is the gallery.js file without code for redirect  - thanks so much - https://jsfiddle.net/harlemrag/mfowLyzb/1/#&togetherjs=D3rLdPSOON

Comment: @WayneEllery there are more .js and .css files that cant be added in jsfiddle - Here's the link to all the files -  Thanks so much   https://fil.email/ycpYEilo